# TikZ, arrow, looking for ++++++> style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm wondering if it's possible to draw, by `\tikzstyle`, this style of arrow : `+++++>`. Thanks, Simon

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide more information on what `+` symbols should represent in paths?

Comment: Is `[decorate=crosses]` close enough? If so you can maybe obtain plusses using rotation...

Comment: As '\tikzstyle{dim}=[->,>=latex,thin,dashed]' give me this style of arrow : '---->', 
I want the line to be replaced by a succession of symbols '+'.

Comment: @silama, that is what Bordaigorl suggests with his comment.

Comment: @Bordaigorl: I suspect `crosses` decoration does not have an option to rotate the symbols and make them becoming a plus.

Comment: Maybe something like `decoration={markings, mark=between positions 0 and .9 step 4pt with {\draw[-] (2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);} }` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried '\tikzstyle{dim}=[->,>=latex,thin,decorate=crosses]' and '\tikzstyle{dim}=[decorate=crosses]', but it doesn't work...

Comment: have you included the decorations library? `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an idea: use dashed, and define a decoration which draws the vertical line which crosses each dash to produce a plus:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  pluses/.style={
    dashed,
    decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 1.5pt and 1 step 6pt with {
       \draw[-] (0,1.5pt) -- (0,-1.5pt);
       }
    },
    postaction=decorate,
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin, pluses, ->] (0,0) to[bend left=45] (2,2);
\draw[very thick, red, pluses, ->] (-1,1) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: It works very well. Thanks everybody, thank you JLDiaz.

Comment: @silama: you can even define a `++++>` style for this; according to JLDiaz's answer you need: `\tikzset{++++>/.style={pluses,->}}`, then `\draw[very thick, red, ++++>]...`.